# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26

Tags: java

I am currently learning Java, and when I am running example code from my learning material I am getting an 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26"

```
package com.java24hours;

public class Wheel {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        String phrase[] = {
                "A STITCH IN TIME SAVES NINE",
                "DON'T EAT YELLOW SNOW",
                "EVERY GOOD BOY DOES FINE",
                "I WANT MY MVT",
                "PLAY IT AGAIN, SAM",
                "FROSTY THE SNOWMAN",
                "ONE MORE FOR THE ROAD",
                "HOME FIELD ADVANTAGE",
                "SHEFFIELD WEDNESDAY",
                "GOVER CLEAVLAND OHIO",
                "ZELDA: MAJORAS MASK",
                "SPEGHETTI WESTERN",
                "TEEN TITANS GO",
                "IT'S A WONDERFUL LIFE",
        };
        int [] letterCount = new int [26];
        for(int count = 0; count < phrase.length; count++) {
            String current = phrase[count];
            char[] letters = current.toCharArray();
            for(int count2 = 0; count2 < letters.length; count2++) {
                char lett = letters[count2];
                if ( (lett >= 'A') & (lett <= 'Z')) {
                    letterCount[lett - 'A']++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'z'; count++) {
            System.out.print(count + ": " + 
                    letterCount [count - 'A'] + " ");
            if (count == 'M') {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I am getting the correct output as far as the program goes, but I am unsure why the exception comes up.

By reading other threads I know that for a Java that an array starts with a "0" and when I tried to change the "26" to a "25" it would cause the program not to run.  I am wanting to know if the exception that I am getting is actually an issue, or is it Java telling me that there are unused parts of the array since the array is actually reading that it should be 27 characters long and there is not a value for one.

Comment: Can you give the line whichthrows the error ? it would be so quicker for us

Comment: Where you have `count <= 'z'` (lower case) I think you mean `count <= 'Z'` (upper case). Your loop is going too far and running past the end of the array.

Comment: Why is your `System.out.println()` empty? This will effectively output nothing.

Comment: Also use names for your variables that have sens, like `word` and `wordLetters` rather than poor `count count2`

Comment: @TA `System.out.println()` outputs a newline.

Comment: @khelwood my bad, I should actually read the code first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is trying to go to 'A' to 'z'.  You need to go for 'A' to 'Z' Check for the [ASCII TABLE](https://www.asciitable.com/)

```
for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'Z'; count++) {
            System.out.print(count + ": " +
                    letterCount [count - 'A'] + " ");
            if (count == 'M') {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
```

With this change the out put will be

```
A: 22 B: 1 C: 2 D: 12 E: 31 F: 8 G: 6 H: 7 I: 15 J: 1 K: 1 L: 10 M: 9 
N: 18 O: 20 P: 2 Q: 0 R: 9 S: 16 T: 19 U: 1 V: 6 W: 7 X: 0 Y: 7 Z: 1
```

Comment: @azro You are correct the code is trying to go!

Comment: Okay but Java doesn't use ASCII. See [Java Character Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is around `count - 'A'` and your bounds : `A - z` :

- When `count` will value `A`, you'll access index 0, it's ok
- ...
- When `count` will value `Z`, you'll access index 25, still ok BUT you're not yet to `z` bound
- So it'll continue, `count` will value `[` and you'll try to access index `26` **!**

as [***Ascii Table state***](https://d9np3dj86nsu2.cloudfront.net/image/180a43d5e9d27f17178adc0294f432d3) and [***Demo***](https://ideone.com/WLJHtX)

---

You need to stop at `Z`

```
for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'Z'; count++) {
    System.out.print(count + ": " + letterCount [count - 'A'] + " ");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Greatly appreciate it!